# Creating a d3 style chained function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, chaining, chain

I get how to do chained functions like a = x().y().z(), but I was looking to make something like d3 shape functions with 2 sets of parens at the end.  ex: d = d3.line().curve('somecurve')([[10, 60], [40, 90]]).

The best I got is:

```
function gc() {
    gen = function (z) {
      console.log(x + y + z)
    }
    gen.setx = function(d) {x = d; return(this)}
    gen.sety = function(d) {y = d; return(this)}

    return gen
}

a = gc().setx(1).sety(2)
b = gc().setx(3).sety(4)

a(5)
b(6)
```

Which results in:

> 12

> 13

Which is clearly wrong as the second call is somehow overwriting the x,y state of the first call.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `x`, `y`, and `gen` are global variables. So if two of these functions are both writing to them, they'll be overwritten. You'll need to create a separate set of variables each time `gc` is called. For example:

```js
function gc() {
    let x = 0; // <----- added
    let y = 0; // <----- added
    const gen = function (z) {
      console.log(x + y + z)
    }
    gen.setx = function(d) {x = d; return(this)}
    gen.sety = function(d) {y = d; return(this)}

    return gen
}

a = gc().setx(1).sety(2)
b = gc().setx(3).sety(4)

a(5)
b(6)
```